# Windows 7 -- I have given my domain account administrator membership, but I still have to run VS2008 as 'Administrator' because it deals with IIS

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts

Windows 7 -- I have given my domain account administrator membership, but I still have to run VS2008 as 'Administrator' because it deals with IIS.

This is weird, does any one have any ideas as to why this is happening?

It also happens with other things, file copies, etc... It says I will need administrator approval, but then I can just click go anyways. Is there a way to disable all this go around and just make my domain account with admin privileges to the local machine behave as though it were an administrator. (Which it is)

Here is an example, I am an admin, but I still get the image below

Worse, I can just click continue and it lets me go on

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 (and Vista), *nothing* runs as administrator until you tell it to.  Giving your account Administrator privileges just gives you the right to use the "Run as Administrator" feature.

You can improve things a little bit by right-clicking on the program icon and selecting "Run as Administrator" on the Compatibility tab in the dialog box that opens. That's better than having to remember to run it as administrator every time you use it, but you should still see a prompt when the app starts asking you if it's okay to run the app as an administrator. If you turn off UAC the prompt will go away as well, but I don't recommend that.